# Rails 3: Would PostgreSQL be a better fit than MySQL for partitioning tables?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, rails-postgresql

Is Postgres a better option than MySQL for partitioning tables by date?

How well does Postgres play with Rails and when it comes to partitioning tables?

The purpose of my application will be to provide metrics in a similar fashion as Google Analytics. The data is not being collected in real-time so there is no emphasis on fast inserts, but there will be millions of rows with the most recent data being accessed the most frequently.

A few additional key points..

- Database replication and backups are **not** as important as ease of development and the speed of the application.
- New data can be inserted at leisure. The database will primarily be used for select queries.
- The server will be a Debian 6 box running Rails 3.1 and Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Have you considered alternate database storage engines, like Redis, MongoDB, and Cassandra?

Comment: I agree that NoSQL solutions would be easier to scale, and I actually already store all the incoming data in Redis, but how well do these solutions play with Rails? Mongoid looks promising, I must say..

Comment: Very well, you just don't use ActiveRecord. They all have Ruby drivers that you can use instead.

Answer (score 1):

Well, with PostgreSQL, partitioning tables is at least possible, if you want them to still look like a single table or not to the front-end.  I don't believe this is elegantly doable in MySQL without a lot of VIEW maintenance.  So yes, it would be a better fit if this is what you want to do.

However what PostgreSQL may give you is a set of tools that can avoid you having to partition your tables at all.  Things like partial indexes can give you many of the benefits of partitioned tables without all the costs (i.e. a sort of partition-lite, partitioning indexes instead of data).